# Apache doesn't execute php files, but mod_php5 is enabled

Tags: php, module, apache2, installation, execution

I don't understand why. Instead of execute php files, he services me as download.

In the downloaded file there is php source.

My test file is very simple, its called info.php

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost some_ip:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/my_vhost/htdocs
ServerName www.my_vhost.com

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/my_vhost/htdocs/>
    Options All -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog  /var/www/vhosts/my_vhost/logs/error.log
LogLevel warn   
CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/my_vhost/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

In the apache2 conf i have the line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Apache enabled modules:

```
apache2ctl -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 bw_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 dav_svn_module (shared)
 authz_svn_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 perl_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 python_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

**What i have to try to debug and solve this?**

I have phpmyadmin installed too and it works correctly.

Comment: could be an add-type directive in a .htaccess or other .conf file, overriding the one you've got in your apache2.conf.

Comment: DirectoryIndex is missing? How it is supposed to be set?

Comment: Does plain HTML render normally?

Comment: @avastreg whats in .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

They were 2:

- **plesk**, which configuration was confusing me and giving me back the file to download
- the lack of `NameVirtualHost 111.22.33.44:80` in my virtual hosts

so i've excluded all the include by plesk, and then the problem was clear; the virtual host could not be resolved because there was another ip-based virtual host before that.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have this files "php5.conf" and "php5.load" into "mods-available" (default path : /etc/apache2/mods-available)

If not, create them like so:

php5.conf :

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch ".ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/site>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

php5.load :

```
# default PATH : /usr/lib/apache2/module/libphp5.so
LoadModule php5_module PATH/libphp5.so
```

Phpmyadmin add link of config file name "phpmyadmin.conf" into "/etc/apache2/conf.d" with the necessary instruction for enable php :

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_value include_path .
    </IFModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: yes i have both, and the phpmyadmin conf. so myadmin works, but my vhosts no..

Comment: Thank you! I needed that tiny bit of text `php5_module`! I had to downgrade from PHP 7 to PHP 5 and the format of the `LoadModule` statement was completely different, as was the file name. I had everything else, but `mod_php5` was not working.